Refactoring marshmellow schema to pydantic 2
I have been struggling to refactor this marshmellow schema to pydantic 2. Problem is with AttributeValue field. When I refactor this to pydantic, I always get strange errors regarding this field. This attribute field is dynamic that can accept many values as you can see it in _get_field function. I cannot seem to find correct way to define similar field in pydantic. Any suggestions?
import copy

from dataclasses import dataclass
from marshmallow import fields, schema, ValidationError, validates_schema, post_load, Schema


@dataclass(frozen=True, kw_only=True)
class Attribute:
    """
    A dataclass for storing the attributes of a segment.
    """

    id: str
    value: str | list[str]



def get_validation_error_kwargs(field_name=None):
    kwargs = {}
    if field_name is not None:
        kwargs["field_name"] = field_name

    return kwargs


def make_single_option_validator(options, field_name=None):
    validation_error_kwargs = get_validation_error_kwargs(field_name)

    def validate(value):
        if value not in options:
            raise ValidationError(
                f'"{value}" is not a valid option', **validation_error_kwargs
            )

    return validate


def make_multiple_option_validator(options, field_name=None):
    def validate(values):
        invalid_values = set(values).difference(options)
        if invalid_values:
            invalid = ", ".join(sorted(f'"{value}"' for value in invalid_values))
            raise ValueError(f"The following values are not valid options: {invalid} ")

    return validate


class AttributeValue(fields.Field):
    """
    A field for validating and serialising attribute values.
    """

    type_fields = {
        "single": fields.String(),
        "multi": fields.List(fields.String),
        "boolean": fields.Boolean(),
        "range": fields.Integer(),
        "account": fields.String(),
        "supplier": fields.List(fields.String),
    }
    option_validator_factories = {
        "single": make_single_option_validator,
        "account": make_single_option_validator,
        "multi": make_multiple_option_validator,
        "supplier": make_multiple_option_validator,
    }
    # Used to produce ``None`` when the attribute ID isn't valid and a
    # type-specific field can't be found. This is required because
    # even though the ID is validated elsewhere, this field's
    # validation will always run.
    null_field = fields.Constant(None)

    def _get_field(self, attribute_id):
        manifest = self.parent.manifest  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
        manifest_attribute = manifest.attributes.get(attribute_id)
        if manifest_attribute:
            attribute_type = manifest_attribute["type"]
            field = self.type_fields[attribute_type]

            # Check if the attribute type requires that its value is
            # validated against a set of options
            if (
                attribute_type in self.option_validator_factories
                and "option_labels" in manifest_attribute
            ):
                field = copy.deepcopy(field)

                if not self.parent.context.get("skip_attributes_validation", False):
                    # Proceed with attribute's option validation
                    # only if the campaign isn't finalized (frozen).
                    # For finalized (frozen) campaing,
                    # there will be 'skip_attributes_validation' == True.
                    field.validators = [
                        self.option_validator_factories[attribute_type](
                            manifest_attribute["option_labels"]
                        )
                    ]

            return field


        return self.null_field

    def _serialize(self, value, attr, obj, **kwargs):
        field = self._get_field(obj.id)
        return field.serialize(attr, obj)

    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data, **kwargs):
        field = self._get_field(data["id"])
        return field.deserialize(value, attr, data)


class AttributeSchema(Schema):
    """
    A schema for validating and serialising attributes.
    """

    id = fields.String()
    value = AttributeValue(allow_none=True)

    @property
    def manifest(self):
        return self.context["manifest"]

    @validates_schema
    def validate_values(self, data, **_):
        if data.get("value") is None:
            raise ValidationError(f"{data['id']!r} value may not be null.")

    @post_load
    def make_attribute(self, data, **kwargs):
        return Attribute(**data)
    

And this is example test case:
from datetime import date

import pytest
from marshmallow import ValidationError

from .pricing import Attribute, DateRange
from .schema import AttributeSchema


@pytest.fixture
def schema(manifest):
    """
    Return a ``AttributeSchema`` instance bound to Manifest.
    """
    return AttributeSchema(context={"manifest": manifest})


TYPE_INPUTS = [
    # Single
    (
        {"id": "industry", "value": "appliances"},
        Attribute(id="industry", value="appliances"),
    ),
    # Multi
    (
        {"id": "day_part", "value": ["am", "pm"]},
        Attribute(id="day_part", value=["am", "pm"]),
    ),
    # Boolean
    ({"id": "restricted", "value": True}, Attribute(id="restricted", value=True)),
]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("payload, expected_attribute", TYPE_INPUTS)
def test_deserialisiaton_succeeds(schema, payload, expected_attribute):
    """
    Each supported attribute value type should be appropriately
    deserialised.
    """
    attribute = schema.load(payload)

    assert attribute == expected_attribute

As you can see attribute value can be one of multiple types and should be validated correctly.
Any suggestions or guidance will be appreciated.

How do you expect bool value to pass in test case, when you annotated value like str | list[str]?
